# CPU temp on ubuntu 12.04 higher than on windows 5-10C in "normal usage"

Tags: hardware, cpu

This is something that I've been seeing on older ubuntu versions, too. I bought a new laptop recently and am seeing the same old thing.

It's Asus K53S with i7 2670QM processor, 8G ram and a somewhat slow HDD (5400rpm). 
While surfing the web with ~5 tabs, on windows, my core temp is on avg ~51C, and on ubuntu it stays at ~56C.

When installing new software etc it gets higher, but I guess it's something to be expected.

Any ideas why the difference and can I somehow lower it (without undervolting)?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `jupiter`, it lowered my cpu temperature significantly. Plus you should check threads in askubuntu, similar question was asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it could be that the kernel isn't doing a great job at powering down devices when it could, or it could be that you have some busy applications that are keeping the machine from being idle.

Consider looking at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues

and also:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks

Comment: thx... 3am here, but i'll check it out tomorrow. appreciate your answer, very much!