# Are those temperatures high for my computer?

Tags: 12.04, cpu, overheating, temperature

I've just erased Windows 7 because I got so pissed off at him and decided to replace it with Ubuntu 12.04.

Im kinda new to Ubuntu and I´ve downloaded Psensor since I was feeling my notebook a little hotter than when I used W7.

My notebook is a Samsung 700G7A.

RAM:16GB Ram

HDD: 2Tera HDD

Processor:Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8

Temperatures:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsPTX.jpg

What are the CORE and temp temperature?

Are those temperature fine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/53469/Intel-Core-i7-2670QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), the TJUNCTION is 100 degrees c.  Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die. So you're OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/168730/cpu-temp-on-ubuntu-12-04-higher-than-on-windows-5-10c-in-normal-usage

Answer (score 1):

An Intel Core i7 process has 4 physical cores. core0 through core3 are the temperatures of each of these physical cores. The temperatures seem perfectly within normal operating range. According to the [Intel ARK page for your i7-2670QM](http://ark.intel.com/products/53469/Intel-Core-i7-2670QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz?q=i7-2670QM) processor, 48C is well within accepted parameters (max 100C).

Temp1 and Temp2 are typically temperature measurements at another point on your computer's motherboard. Exactly where these temperatures are taken on your particular system can vary from manufacturer to manufacturer but it is often taken from the northbridge, southbridge or CPU socket. Since the temperature of Temp1 and Temp2 are the same in the image you've provided as the temperature of the CPU cores, I would suspect that these are taken on the CPU socket and another location very nearby, possibly overall CPU temperature (all 4 cores together). This would indicate that, again, 48C is well within acceptable parameters.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Sometimes, like when I open many tabs or many videos, the temp1 and HDD go from 48C to 60. Should I get worried?

Comment: 60C is still well within the TJUNCTION max for your processor (100C).

Comment: Man, it gets higher so easily. It cant be normal. I installed Gnome as a guy told me to, but nothing has changed. Take a look at temp1 and temp2: http://i.imgur.com/EVVzqfr.png